# Problem playing large MP4 (500 MB) video files in Android 2.1

Tags: 2.1-eclair, video, files

When I try to play a large MP4 video file (500 MB), say a film on my phone, it plays the audio but not the video.

I have checked running a smaller MP4 file (5 MB), and it plays fine.

Even when the video is listed in the video gallery, the video thumbnail is not displayed. [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) shows that video frame cannot be obtained with a status -24.

What changes are needed to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using a stock ROM?

Comment: Try converting the video using in the same format using Pc suite for your mobile

Answer (score 4):

Does the .mp4 play as a video on a desktop OS? Can you 'vouch' for the source?

.mp4 is a container format and may well only contain audio, or is corrupt and the player can only salvage the audio...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14

Comment: Yes the .mp4 plays correctly on the desktop OS (ubuntu). 
I even tried changing the resolution of the video using converter to match that to my mobile device but i still have the same problem.

I also see that No thumbnail is getting created for this file and an error is returned by the opencore layer for getting a video frame as "PVMFErrMaxReached" . Is there a limitation set on the size of the file.


@Onik: No the codec is fine as I am able to play the mp4 video file with same codec properties but of shorter duration. The video Codec is H264/AVC.

Comment: Please add the replys as comments to the answer, this way the user gets notified of the reply. Just to make sure, both of the videos use only the baseline profile of AVC?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the MP4 file contains video packed with a wrong/unsupported codec. Try recoding the video to a format that's supported by your phone.

A quick search showed [Videora Android Converter](http://www.videora.com/en-us/Converter/android/). It seems easy to use and converts to formats supported by Android.

Answer (score 0):

The [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) app is the best one I've found for playing a variety of file formats and codecs.  I suspect that the problem might be, as @onik suggested, that the codec used is not supported by your video player.  There's also an "app" that supplies additional codecs.